# Android Mediarecorder Flipped mirrored output

Tags: android, mediarecorder

I am making an app who can record a video but the output is flipped mirrored which is annoying me. The preview is perfect but when I play the video from a videoview it's mirrored (also saved as mirrored).

This is my code to configure the Mediarecorder I use.

```
    mediaRecorder = new MediaRecorder();
    mediaRecorder.setPreviewDisplay(holder.getSurface());
    mediaRecorder.setCamera(camera);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioSource(MediaRecorder.AudioSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSource(MediaRecorder.VideoSource.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setOutputFormat(MediaRecorder.OutputFormat.MPEG_4);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoSize(640, 480);
    mediaRecorder.setOrientationHint(270);
    mediaRecorder.setVideoEncoder(MediaRecorder.VideoEncoder.DEFAULT);
    mediaRecorder.setAudioEncoder(MediaRecorder.AudioEncoder.AAC_ELD);
    mediaRecorder.setMaxDuration(50000);
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Were you able to figure it out? Having the same issue.